# Any Windows phone with temperature sensors?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, blu-win-hd

I have [BLU Win HD LTE](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/BLU-Win-HD-LTE--Unlocked/productID.316711500) and probably it doesn't have temperature sensors (I didn't find it in description).

But do any Windows phone has them? For measure temperature around?

I check [Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=thermometer&form=apps) and see only apps for temperature outside. But I want room temperature.

I see this [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colortiger.thermo&hl=en) for this, but can it be done using Windows phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currently no Windows Phone / Mobile devices, that have sensors for ambient temperature, neither is there currently a way for developers to access them if there were.

Try requesting support for this through the feedback app.